# Derivation of the $u$-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have to derive $u$-substitution based on this equation : 
$$\frac{df(U)}{dx}=f'(U)\frac{dU}{dx}$$ where $U$ is a function of $x$. I have the feeling I have to integrate both sides but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Claim : $\displaystyle \quad\int_a^b f(U(x))U'(x)dx = \int_{U(a)}^{U(b)} f(u)du$.

*Proof* : Suppose $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, that is, $F'=f$. Then, the right-hand-side is equal to
$$F(U(b))-F(U(a))$$
In the other hand, notice that
$$(F\circ U)'(x)=F'(U(x))U'(x)=f(U(x))U'(x)$$
then 
$$\int_a^b f(U(x))U'(x)dx = (F\circ U)(b)-(F\circ U)(a)=F(U(b))-F(U(a)).$$